# Padding at the bottom of a scrolling column with a fixed-width header

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, layout, padding

So I have a webpage with a column.  The column has a fixed header up top, and a large scrolling body section, and the HTML/CSS below works fine for this.

*The problem*: I want to add padding to the bottom of the body, so if you scroll all the way down, you get some whitespace instead of having everything jammed right up to the bottom edge.  Adding `padding-bottom: 50px` to `.body` works perfectly in Chrome; however, in Firefox, it appears that using the `bottom` property means that `padding-bottom` is ignored.  If you drop `bottom`, the padding appears, but the scrollbar disappears.

**test.html**

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/test.css">
<div class="column">
  <div class="header">
    Fixed header
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <h1>Body</h1>
    Where's the bottom padding?
  </div>
</div>
```

**test.css**

```
.column {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

.body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  padding-bottom: 50px;  /* Broken in Firefox */
}
```

JSFiddle for the above: http://jsfiddle.net/jpatokal/PBwVa/

Is there a way around this?  The one workaround I came up with was using a string of `:last-child` selectors to add padding to the very last element within `.body` instead, but, eww.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding a inner div inside the div.body with a margin-bottom seems to work in your jsfiddle.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/test.css">
<div class="column">
  <div class="header">
    Fixed header
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="inner">
      <h1>Body</h1>
        Where's the bottom padding?
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

and the (extra) css:

```
.body .inner {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround would be to wrap your content in another div, and add your padding (or margin) to that div instead of the scrolling `.body` div:

```
  <div class="body">
    <div class="body-content">
      <h1>Body</h1>
      Where's the bottom padding?
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the css...

```
.body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
.body-content {
  padding-bottom: 50px;  /* should work */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more workaround when you don't want to add extra DIVs.

```
.body:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Working in FF, Chrome, IE8-10.